# Fail: ABORTED: No motion plan found. No execution attempted

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have used moveit api but with function "group.setPoseTarget(pose1)" it give " Fail: ABORTED: No motion plan found. No execution attempted" and at terminal of rviz it give

```
[ INFO] [1469775045.492605776]: LBKPIECE1: Created 1 (1 start + 0 goal) states in 1 cells (1 start (1 on boundary) + 0 goal (0 on boundary))
```

[ INFO] [1469775045.492659516]: No solution found after 5.050528 seconds
[ INFO] [1469775045.528370905]: Unable to solve the planning problem
[ INFO] [1469775050.530937767]: Combined planning and execution request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning and execution pipeline.
[ INFO] [1469775051.139609983]: Planning attempt 1 of at most 1
[ INFO] [1469775051.169520219]: LBKPIECE1: Starting planning with 1 states already in datastructure
[ERROR] [1469775056.175594376]: LBKPIECE1: Unable to sample any valid states for goal tree
[ INFO] [1469775056.175806507]: LBKPIECE1: Created 1 (1 start + 0 goal) states in 1 cells (1 start (1 on boundary) + 0 goal (0 on boundary))
[ INFO] [1469775056.175905203]: No solution found after 5.006600 seconds
[ INFO] [1469775056.185580711]: Unable to solve the planning problem

can any one tell me how to solve this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240723/fail:-aborted:-no-motion-plan-found.-no-execution-attempted/) by [FaredEtman](https://answers.ros.org/users/27498/faredetman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-07-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bhavyadoshi26](https://answers.ros.org/users/26692/bhavyadoshi26/) on 2016-12-21**:
Have you solved it?

**Comment by [zichenxiaoxu](https://answers.ros.org/users/40019/zichenxiaoxu/) on 2019-02-20**:
Do you solve this problem? I have the same error, but I don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This can have several causes.

- `pose1` might simply be unreachable by the arm -> use a pose of which you know that it is reachable
- `pose1` is reachable but the inverse kinematics plugin failed to find a joint configuration that results in the end-effector being near that pose -> use a different IK or different parameters (trac_ik or a specialized ikfast perform good)
- The planner failed to find a path to the goal -> is there a path by which you can move from the current configuration to the goal configuration (within the specified software limits)
- if there are paths the planner should be able to find, you might want to try a different planner -> e.g. `group.setPlannerId("RRTConnectkConfigDefault")`
- the planner might find the path with more time available -> `group.setPlanningTime(<insert-time-limit-here>)`

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2016-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on 2017-12-02**:
Hi, I have a question that before I set the pose goal, how can I know whether the pgose goal is reachable? Is there any funtion in moveit to solve this problem?

**Comment by [nmelchert](https://answers.ros.org/users/29154/nmelchert/) on 2018-09-10**:
Is there a Python functionality for that?

**Comment by [RobertZickler](https://answers.ros.org/users/52301/robertzickler/) on 2021-07-08**:
@tengfei and @nmelchert have a look at [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/319938/validityreturn-state-of-moveits-groupplan/?answer=320009#post-id-320009)

So in short:

```
plan = group.plan()
if not plan.joint_trajectory.points:
    # Error
```